# How come opens does not provide resources in module system globally?

Tags: resources, java-platform-module-system

I have two modules A,B and I want to access resources of A from B. Even if I open packages from A I still can not access its resources from B with a B class anchor. I still have to use a A class anchor like this:

```
ClassOfA.class.getResource();
```

Unfortunately I have an environment where it is not so easy to specify the anchor. It sounds a bit awkward that opens opens everything for reflection but the resources are somehow hidden still when not using the correct anchor.

Is this a generic design principle or a feature which might be introduced later (JDK 17 here)?

Answer (score 2):

## The resolution of resources in `java.lang.Class` changed for named modules

It's not that the resources are hidden, but the behaviour of [`Class.getResource(<name>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) changed:

> If this class is in a named Module then this method will attempt to **find the resource in the module**.

This is different than the behaviour of [`ClassLoader.getResource(<name>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

> Resources in named modules are subject to the **encapsulation rules** specified by Module.getResourceAsStream. Additionally, ..., this method will only find resources in packages of named modules **when the package is opened unconditionally** ...

### An Example

Let's assume you have...

- a class A in package `org.example.a` of module `module.a`
- a class B in package `org.example.b` of module `module.b`.
- Module `module.b` depends on `module.a`.
- Module `module.a` also contains a resource `propsofa.properties` in `src/main/resources/org/example/a`.

### Before Java 9 modules

Before Java 9 modules these expressions could have been used interchangeably:

1. `A.class.getResource("propsofa.properties")`
2. `B.class.getResource("/org/example/a/propsofa.properties")`
3. `B.class.getClassLoader().getResource("org/example/a/propsofa.properties")`
4. `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("org/example/a/propsofa.properties")`

Note that in #2 the name starts with "/" to force absolute resolution.

### With Java 9 modules

With Java 9 modules the results of the expressions above are different and roughly interpreted like this (all of them require to check module encapsulation):

1. Resolve `propsofa.properties` relative to class A and look for it in `module.a`.
   Works when opened through `module-info.java` or `--add-opens`.
2. Look for `org/example/a/propsofa.properties` in `module.b` **(!)**.
   Does *never* work for this example.
3. Try to derive *module from package name* `org/example/a` and look in that module, which is `module.a` in this case. If not found there, try to find it on the **class path**.
   Works only when opened through `module-info.java` or when on class path, *not* with `--add-opens`.
4. Roughly same as #3. Result might be different, if classes have been loaded by different class loaders.

### Restriction of --add-opens

Adding access to resources with `--add-opens` (to fix a missing `open <package-name>` clause in the containing module) only works when resources are retrieved through a corresponding class (like in example #1 above) or through the module.

Access through a class loader does not work. The Java class loaders only respect static openings for resources (might be different for custom class loaders, though). The motivation behind it is a bit unclear, it might be a bug.

```java
/*** --add-opens examples ***/
// this works:
A.class.getResource("propsofa.properties");
// this works, too:
ModuleLayer.boot().findModule("module.a").ifPresent(module -> {
    try (InputStream is = module.getResourceAsStream("org/example/a/propsofa.properties")) {
        // do sth with the input stream
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
// but this don't (returned URL is null):
A.class.getClassLoader().getResource("org/example/a/propsofa.properties")
```

## How to access resources from a different module

This is a general list from best to worst, not only reflecting the question.

1. Simply **don't**!. Leave access to resources up to the containing module. Expose the contents, if necessary.
2. Return the InputStream from a factory method that resides in the containing module.
3. Add `open <package-name>` to the containing class name, export the path as a constant (`public static final`) and use one of...

   - `UsingClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`
   - `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`
   - `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`.
4. Put it on the **class path**. This is still possible and does not have the restrictions of the Java 9 module system.
5. Use the build system to copy the resource from one module to the other (and don't expose it).

Hope this helps.